# Does the "Highlighting stats" note still apply to what reported in the "Admin Summary" page?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

I noticed that the information given in the "Admin Summary" page is not anymore highlighted with two different colors. I noticed the change in the past two days.

Does the following note still apply to that page?

> Highlighting stats: 50% or less of the median, 25% or less of the median.

The highlighting colors vanished, but the values I first saw highlighted didn't change much to justify a different color.

The software revision used on Drupal Answers is now 2012.6.20.3051, which is the exact revision used on Meta Stack Overflow, but it is different from the revision used on Stack Overflow (2012.6.20.3034).

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed both colors

Comment: Do you mean both the colors are still used?

Comment: Yes, and appear to be used just as they always were. I think there's some other criterial to them though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are definitively still used. This is a partial screenshot of that page which shows some number in a different color. For *Drupal Answers* the colors are respectively orange, and red.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]